# Openssl CLI AES-XTS and AES-CCM support

Tags: cryptography, openssl

Is there anyone out there who have tested AES-CCM and AES-XTS using openssl CLI. ? Whether openssl supports AES-XTS? I was having a backup plan of creating custom API if CLI does not supports XTS and CCM . I googled regarding the same. But I expect a better feedback from openssl and cryptographic experts.

Comment: Why do you need experts to tell you if something is supported in OpenSSL? That's a documentation question. Is there something more specific that you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, those cipher modes are only supported by the openssl library but not by the CLI tools (as of v1.1.1).

For once, this is something where openssl even has pretty clear error messages:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-128-ccm -K 0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f10 -iv 00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
enc: AEAD ciphers not supported                                                                                                         

$ openssl enc -aes-128-xts-K 0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f10 -iv 00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
enc XTS ciphers not supported
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I ll try it

Comment: @ANjali If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it as the correct one.